# Failed to > instantiate module ngMaterial due to: Error: [$injector:nomod]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

So I used Yeoman to create an angular application, using the generator fountain-angular1 and I am trying to use angular materials with it. I've seen other post about getting this error from ngMaterial for different reasons, but none of the resolutions seemed to work for me.

[image]

I have installed the dependencies, and put them in the specific order as suggested. I am pretty new to Angular so I am guessing that I am probably missing something basic. I spent so much time trying to get this to work, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

index.js file:

```
var angular = require('angular');

var techsModule = require('./app/techs/index');
require('angular-ui-router');
var routesConfig = require('./routes');

var main = require('./app/main');
var header = require('./app/header');
var title = require('./app/title');
var footer = require('./app/footer');

require('./index.scss');

angular
  .module('app', [techsModule, 'ui.router', 'ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate', 'ngAria'])
  .config(routesConfig)
  .component('app', main)
  .component('fountainHeader', header)
  .component('fountainTitle', title)
  .component('fountainFooter', footer);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>FountainJS</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://fountainjs.io/assets/imgs/fountain.png" />
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <ui-view></ui-view>
  <script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="/node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="/node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.9",
    "angular-animate": "^1.5.0",
    "angular-aria": "^1.5.0",
    "angular-filter": "^0.5.15",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.3",
    "angular-moment": "^1.0.1",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "babel-core": "^6.0.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "^1.5.16",
    "@types/angular-mocks": "^1.5.5",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.33",
    "angular-mocks": "^1.5.0-beta.2",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.8.0",
    "@types/angular-ui-router": "^1.1.34",
    "del": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp": "gulpjs/gulp#4ed9a4a3275559c73a396eff7e1fde3824951ebb",
    "gulp-hub": "frankwallis/gulp-hub#d461b9c700df9010d0a8694e4af1fb96d9f38bf4",
    "gulp-filter": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "gulp-angular-filesort": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-insert": "^0.5.0",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.1.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.9.11",
    "browser-sync-spa": "^1.0.3",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "karma-angular-filesort": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.1.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.6",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.20",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.9.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.2.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "webpack-fail-plugin": "^1.0.5",
    "ng-annotate-loader": "^0.0.10",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "eslint": "^3.2.2",
    "eslint-config-xo-space": "^0.12.0",
    "eslint-config-angular": "^0.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "^1.3.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp",
    "serve": "gulp serve",
    "serve:dist": "gulp serve:dist",
    "test": "gulp test",
    "test:auto": "gulp test:auto"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "globals": {
      "expect": true
    },
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "jasmine": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "xo-space"
    ]
  }
}
```

File path:
[image]

Comment: it looks like `node_modules` is one level above your publicly accessible files. You're probably best combining them into a single file using something like [`gulp-bower-files`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bower-files)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments and variety of solutions! I actually found out what my problem was. Since I had already installed it with npm, I just needed to require angular-materials in my index.js file, right under where it requires Angular. It needed to look like this:

```
var angular = require('angular');
require('angular-material');
```

With that, I don't need to use these references at all:

```
<script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
```

and then add it to the module:

```
angular
  .module('app', [techsModule, 'ui.router', 'ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate'])
  .config(routesConfig)
  .component('app', main)
```

Hope this helps anyone else having this issue. Really simple fix!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access modules from node_modules like this

```
<script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
```

because you have this structure

```
node_modules
app/index.html
```

so `src="/node_modules/..."` in your html, references to `app/node_modules...` which does not exist.

you could try changing `src="/node_modules/whatever"` to `src="../node_modules/whatever` which makes sense, but it depends on your server, that usually does not allow parent references beyond server root folder.

For a permanent solution, you need to reference your files that are inside node_modules from app/something, you can do this by either making a link or copying files. Gulp (that is being used in fountain-angular1) should have a method to do this. Try running `gulp build` and see if your angular modules are being copied into some directory inside `app/`

Another option is for you to do `bower install angular-aria angular-animate angular-material` and then reference files from index to `../bower_components/angular-whatever/angular-whatever.js`

Comment: Thank you for responding! So I tried gulp build and it gives me a ton of errors like::::  @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ multi angular angular-animate angular-aria angular-filter angular-material angular-moment angular-ui-router babel-core webpack
ERROR in ./~/isexe/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/myname/Documents/appname/node_modules/isexe'
 @ ./~/isexe/index.js 1:9-22
 @ ./~/which/which.js
 @ ./~/node-gyp/lib/build.js
 @ ./~/node-gyp/lib ^\.\/.*$
 @ ./~/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js

Do I need to reinstall all my dependencies with bower?

Comment: I also tried adding the ../ to the beginning which didn't work.